# Using lamda to compare two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is like this:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [1,4,5]})`

If column A has the same value as column B, output 1, else 0.

I want to output like this:

```
    A   B   is_equal
0   1   1   1
1   2   4   0
2   3   5   0
```

I figured out `df['is_equal'] = np.where((df['A'] == df['B']), 1, 0)` worked fine.

But I want to use lambda here because I used a similar line in another case before. `df['is_equals'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if df['A']==1 else 0, axis=1)` won't work. It threw the error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` Why did this error happen and how can I fix the code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you attempt to do is very inefficient. Don not do it. `.apply` should not be used when other solutions are possible. The best solution is:

```
df['is_equal'] = (df['A'] == df['B']).astype(int)
```

But if you insist:

```
df.apply(lambda row: int(row['A'] == row['B']), axis=1)
```

The latter answer is 2,5 times slower. The original `np.where` is the fastest.

Comment: Can you kindly explain why didn't your lambda code throw an error? I know lambda is kind of slow, but its not working kind of bugs me because I successfully used it before already.

Comment: Because your code has df["A"]==1 (a Series) instead of x["A"]==1 (a scalar). A scalar is always T or F, but a Series could partially T.

Answer (score 2):

I also agree with DYZ's opinion. But if you want to use `.apply` anyway, I can suggest something like this.

```
df['is_equal'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x.A == x.B else 0, axis=1)
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain your code please? I assume x is the value that's gonna be in the column `is_equal`, whether 1 or 0. So, what does `x.A` mean? Why does x refer to the dataframe in the condition?

Comment: That's the way it works. This is called dot notation, which is comparable to brackets notation. You can write a code in this way for access a pandas dataframe column. Please refer to the link below.
https://www.dataschool.io/pandas-dot-notation-vs-brackets/

Comment: It's just me not familiar with DataFrame lambda syntax. For those who are still confused, this might come in handy: <https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/applying-lambda-functions-to-pandas-dataframe/>